# Is there a package like bigmemory in R that can deal with large list objects?

Tags: r, list, bigdata

I know that the R package bigmemory works great in dealing with large matrices and data frames. However, I was wondering if there is any package or any ways to efficiently work with large list.

Specifically, I created a list with its elements being vectors. I have a for loop and during each iteration, multiple values were appended to a selected element in that list (a vector). At first, it runs fast, but when the iteration is over maybe 10000, it slows down gradually (one iteration takes about a second). I'm going to go through about 70000 to 80000 iterations, and the list would be so large after that.

So I was just wondering if there is something like big.list as the big.matrix in the bigmemory package that could speed up this whole process.

Thanks!

Comment: why not to transform your list to a matrix with do.call(rbind, your_list) and use bigmemory?

Comment: You say you are 'appending'? If you are using for example c() or rbind() for that, that might be causing your speed and memory issues.  See, http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf, Circle 2 Growing Objects from page 12. Could you perhaps show a minimal example of what you code does?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure if this a helpful answer, but you can interactively work with lists on disk using the `filehash` package.

For example here's some code that makes a disk database, assigns a preallocated empty list to the database, then runs a function (getting the current time) that fills the list in the database.

```
# how many items in the list?
n <- 100000
# setup database on disk
dbCreate("testDB") 
db <- dbInit("testDB")
# preallocate vector in database
db$time <- vector("list", length = n)
# run function using disk object
for(i in 1:n) db$time[[i]] <- Sys.time()
```

There is hardly any use of RAM during this process, however it is **VERY** slow (two orders of magnitude slower than doing it in RAM on some of my tests) due to constant disk I/O. So I'm not sure that this method is a good answer to the question of how you can speed up working on big objects.

Answer (score 1):

[`DSL`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DSL/index.html) package might help. The `DList` object works like a drop in replacement for R's list. Futher, it provides a distributed list like facility too.