# Loading 200MB JSON File into R

Tags: json, r

I am trying to use R's rjson library to upload a 200MB JSON file into R , but I got the `Cannot fit vector over 1KB` error. 
Here's the code I used to load the JSON file into R:

```
UnpackJSON <- function(filePath) 
{
  con <- file(filePath, "r")
  input <- readLines(con, -1L)
  # jsonData <- fromJSON(paste(input, collapse=""))
  jsonData <- sapply(input, fromJSON)
  close(con)
  df <- data.frame(jsonData)
  temp <- rownames(df)
  df <- as.data.frame(t(df))
  colnames(df) <- temp
  rownames(df) <- NULL
  return(df)
}
```

Is there a way to optimize this code or another way to load such a large file into R? I appreciate any input.

Comment: Okay. Is it even possible to load such large data set into R?

Answer (score 2):

Why would you process the JSON data line per line using `sapply`? Couldn't you just say `fromJSON(input)`? I suspect a problem could be that the garbage collector waits for the entire `sapply` loop to finish before deleting any copies that are made in the analysis process (see also the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632902/working-with-large-lists-that-become-too-big-for-ram-when-operated-on#comment23920294_16632902)). So when vectorization does not work (which is greatly preferred), you could try and change the `sapply` loop to a `for` loop and see if that helps.